# How to add line seperators to PhpStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Does anyone know how to add a line separator in PhpStorm?

I know it can be done and I see it a lot but for some reason I can't figure it out how to add one even after researching google for a couple hours.

Check out the image below, there are two line separators, one at the top and one in the middle.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings > Editor > Appearance > Show method separators

Comment: alright i did that but what do i do to add these lines?

Comment: They should be visible now. If not, check your color settings, Editor -> Color & Fonts ->General -> Method separator color